# Recognising gestures from the home screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, gesture, homescreen

I am developing an app for iPhone.

I am looking for a way to run some code once a drag gesture is recognized on the homescreen (or on all screens if possible).

Does anyone know how to get this with the iOS SDK using Xcode and Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app cannot receive gestures anywhere in iOS except within itself and its own views while it's active (not counting system notifications and the app icon).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible. To do this, you will need to hook into the OS at a lower level than is usually allowed.

iOS is locked down much more than Mac OS, I'm afraid.